# How to get rid of famous restaurants and other symbols which are displayed on map in openlayer3?

Tags: openlayers-3, markers

In the web application, I am using openlayer3 to display the map, how to get rid of the various markers like restaurants,ring,fork, etc. from the map ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rotation example</title>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/build/ol.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
            <div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script>
    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                collapsible: false
            })
        }),
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([103.986908, 1.353199]),
            rotation: Math.PI / 6,
            zoom: 18,
        })
    });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the various markers you mention are part of the default OpenStreetMap (OSM) base layer you're using. If would like to get rid of those, you can either:

- Switch to another (base) map provider: MapQuest, MapBox, etc
- Host your own version of OSM

So you can customize the (appearance of the) data in your base layer.

In case of MapQuest, take a look at [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/mapquest.html) on how to set this as your base layer.

In case of switching to MapBox for providing your base layer, you can define your new base layer as shown in [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/help/mapbox-with-openlayers/) (OL3 example is at the bottom of the referenced page).

If case of hosting your own version of OSM, take a look at the [SwitchtoOSM](https://switch2osm.org/) website. By hosting your own copy of OpenStreetMap, you can remove any data you do not want to display (such as restaurants in your case). You can then style the data server side with e.g. Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD). SLD is a common language to style data/maps server side, and is implemented a lot of software (e.g. GeoServer) which is used to serve geodata. [This page provides an introduction to what SLD is and how to use it](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-introduction.html).

Comment: Please see my updated and elaborated answer, which provides you with links to code samples and guides for the options presented.

Comment: hello @DhanaLaxshmi , could you let me know whether my answer has helped you or if you need any clarification on some of the points?

Comment: can u please elaborate on hosting your own version of OSM

Comment: Have a look at the SwitchtoOSM website. The [Serving Tiles section](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) describes several options on how you can host your own version of OSM.